# Pywinauto Internet Explorer

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am trying to control Internet Explorer with pywinauto. Windows 8, IE v11 I am using an example from the how tos and I get an

> ElementNotFoundError{'process': 7616, 'title_re': '.*Windows Internet
>   Explorer.*', 'backend' : u'win32'}

Anyone know how to fix this? Seems like another function must be used but so far I can't find it in the help section.

This line is the problem, even though I am doing what the help sections says

```
ie =  app.window(title_re = ".*Windows Internet Explorer.*")

# GUI Application automation and testing library
# Copyright (C) 2006-2017 Mark Mc Mahon and Contributors
# https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/graphs/contributors
# http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/credits.html
# All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
#
# * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
#   list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#
# * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
#   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
#   and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
#
# * Neither the name of pywinauto nor the names of its
#   contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
#   this software without specific prior written permission.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
# AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
# IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
# DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
# FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
# DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
# SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
# CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
# OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
# OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

from __future__ import print_function

try:
    from pywinauto import application
except ImportError:
    import os.path
    pywinauto_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    pywinauto_path = os.path.split(os.path.split(pywinauto_path)[0])[0]
    import sys
    sys.path.append(pywinauto_path)
    from pywinauto import application

import sys
import time
import os.path

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("please specify a web address to download")
    sys.exit()

web_address = sys.argv[1]

if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    outputfilename = sys.argv[2]
else:
    outputfilename = web_address
    outputfilename = outputfilename.replace('/', '')
    outputfilename = outputfilename.replace('\\', '')
    outputfilename = outputfilename.replace(':', '')

outputfilename = os.path.abspath(outputfilename)


# start IE with a start URL of what was passed in
app = application.Application().start(
    r"c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe {}".format(web_address))

# some pages are slow to open - so wait some seconds
time.sleep(10)

ie =  app.window(title_re = ".*Windows Internet Explorer.*")

# ie doesn't define it's menus as Menu's but actually as a toolbar!
print("No Menu's in IE:", ie.menu_items())
print("They are implemented as a toolbar:", ie.Toolbar3.texts())

ie.type_keys("%FA")
#ie.Toolbar3.press_button("File")
app.SaveWebPage.Edit.set_edit_text(os.path.join(r"c:\.temp", outputfilename))


app.SaveWebPage.Save.close_click()

# if asked to overwrite say yes
if app.SaveWebPage.Yes.Exists():
    app.SaveWebPage.Yes.close_click()

print("saved:", outputfilename)

# quit IE
ie.type_keys("%FC")
```

Comment: Windows version? IE version?

Comment: Windows 8, IE v11

Comment: OK, I see the script was written for older IE versions. We need to refresh it probably using `backend='uia'`. Nearest 2 weeks I'm very busy with my students, main job etc. If you've already read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) (main concept and other useful things) you may try re-writing this example by your own. We 're always welcome pull requests! ;)